# Simple hashing function that is HTML id-friendly and case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, md5, hash

I get some strings from an external source, and I display them in `span`s on my page.

I need a way to get back to those strings using `document.getElementById()` or jQuery's `$("#XXXX")`, so along with each string I get some sort of an identifier, I use that identifier as the ID of the `span`.

The problem is that the identifier I get could contain chars like `+` for example. Which is not allowed as a value for the `id` attribute http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp 
Additionally, these identifiers are case-sensitive. So I thought of using a hashing function like SHA or MD5, to hash the identifiers I get, then use them as ids for my spans, and I can apply the hashing function again to find my element.

This seems complicated for such a simple functionality. Is there a better way to do this? or maybe a very simple hashing function that would guarantee `id`-friendly chars and case-sensitivity? (HTML's `id` is not case-sensitive, that's another reason to consider hashing functions)

Comment: I'd look at using a regex to replace a known set of disallowed characters with something like underscores in the string.

Comment: @kinakuta - my thought as well, but depending on what he's getting back, stripping out the cruft may leave duplicate ids.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ditch the identifier you get and just implement something simple like this:

```
var counter = 0;
function uniqueId(){
    return "Id" + ++counter;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just increment the id's with a number and some sort of string to begin the ID.

The span id's would be "a1", "a2" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the problem is that you're thinking later you'll be getting the same strings and will want to transform them in the same way, and then use these to find the original corresponding elements?

If so, you'll just need to sanitize your strings carefully. A series of regular expressions could help you map from invalid to valid characters, and make the capitals unique. For instance, you could transform `"A"` into `"-a-"`, and `"+"` into `"-plus-"`.

A carefully chosen scheme should guarantee that the chances of a collision (i.e. someone giving you a string that looks like an escaped version of another string) should be very small, and in any case, detectable immediately.

Comment: Yes, you understand my problem exactly right. But the thing is I don't know what other chars that I can get other than the plus..